# Templating with positions and weight

Tags: php, html

Hi I'm trying to create a template where i can dynamically put my modules in any position of the template.

My template will have the following positions:

1. content_top
2. content_bottom
3. column_left
4. column_right
5. middle.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Template with dynamic positions</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<div class="content">
<div class="content_top">All content top will go here</div>
<div class="column_left">All content left will go here</div>
<div class="column_right">All content right will go here</div>
<div class="content_bottom">All content bottom will go here</div>
</div>


<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Say i have created a module which i like to add to content_top with weight of 0.

module-top.php

```
$weight = $_GET['weight'];
<div class="slideshow-<?php echo $weight ?>">
<img src="banner.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

how do i insert this to content_top position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="content_top"><?php include('module-top.php'); ?></div>
```

**EDIT:**
You will have to sort it in javascript. You can use bubble sort.
Like this:

```
var slideshows = $('.content_top div');
var len = slideshows.length;
for(var i = 0;i<len;i++)
    for(var j = 0;j < len - 1; j++)
    {
        slideshows = $('.content_top div');
        if(parseInt(slideshows[j].attr('class').replace('slideshow-', '')) > parseInt(slideshows[j + 1].attr('class').replace('slideshow-', '')))
        {
            slideshows[j].before(slideshows[j+1]);
            slideshows[j+1].remove();
        }
    }
```

This is bubble sort. This will sort all the divs in `content_top`.

Comment: How about the weight?. if i have 2 modules that i will put and i put 0 and 1 to the modules. 0 should go first before 1. How would i check for the weight?

Comment: where do you get this `$weight` from? i mean which file?

Comment: can u use javascript?

Comment: Well yes i can use javascript. How can i detect the weight and position them correctly?

Comment: say foreach($module as $modules){ check for the weight and echo the modules }

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to include JQuery and paste the above code in `$(document).ready(function() { });`.

Answer (score 0):

Include the php file inside the content_top div

```
 <div class="content_top">
 <?php include('module-top.php'); ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: but how should i check for the weight? if i have 2 modules in the same content_top div with 0 and 1 weight?

Comment: weight?? there is no variable in the code called weight

Comment: this is set by user dynamically eg in input $_GET['weight'];